# Adding if statement to a core method in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module

How do I add some functionality to a existing method?

I created a custom module now and need to add some code to `Create.php` file. This is the original:

```
public function initFromOrderItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $orderItem, $qty = null)
    {
        if (!$orderItem->getId()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($this->getSession()->getStoreId())
            ->load($orderItem->getProductId());

        if ($product->getId()) {
            $product->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true);
            $buyRequest = $orderItem->getBuyRequest();
            if (is_numeric($qty)) {
                $buyRequest->setQty($qty);
            }
            $item = $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $buyRequest);
            if (is_string($item)) {
                return $item;
            }

            if ($additionalOptions = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
                $item->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                    array(
                        'product' => $item->getProduct(),
                        'code' => 'additional_options',
                        'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
                    )
                ));
            }

            Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item', array(
                'order_item' => $orderItem,
                'quote_item' => $item
            ));
            return $item;
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

All I need to add is:

```
if (
    !$this->getSession()->getReordered()
    && $orderItem->getOriginalPrice() != $orderItem->getPrice()
) {
    $item->setCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());
}
```

Above the line `if ($additionalOptions = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode(‘additional_options’)) {`

How do I do it in my custom module:

```
<?php

class MyModule_CustomPriceRevert_Model_Sales_Order_Create extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create {

}
```

Comment: If your module is configured correctly, you copy the entire function from the `Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php`  file and insert your if statement where you need it.

Comment: Okey, so I paste my updated function in my custom model. What happens if there are a lot more functions in the original `Create.php` file? Do I have to copy them to my custom model or just this one function that I edited?

Comment: You only have to copy the function(s) that you want to modify.  The rest are pulled in from the parent class `extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create`

Comment: Great, that's all I wanted to know! If you put that as a answer, I can accept it if you wish :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, a properly configured class that extends the one in `Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php` will only need the function you wish to modify (in this case `initFromOrderItem`).  So your final file would look something like this:

```
<?php
class MyModule_CustomPriceRevert_Model_Sales_Order_Create extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create {

    public function initFromOrderItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $orderItem, $qty = null)
    {
        if (!$orderItem->getId()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($this->getSession()->getStoreId())
            ->load($orderItem->getProductId());

        if ($product->getId()) {
            $product->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true);
            $buyRequest = $orderItem->getBuyRequest();
            if (is_numeric($qty)) {
                $buyRequest->setQty($qty);
            }
            $item = $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $buyRequest);
            if (is_string($item)) {
                return $item;
            }
// Custom-code
            if (
                !$this->getSession()->getReordered()
                && $orderItem->getOriginalPrice() != $orderItem->getPrice()
            ) {
                $item->setCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());
            }
// end Custom-code
            if ($additionalOptions = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
                $item->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                    array(
                        'product' => $item->getProduct(),
                        'code' => 'additional_options',
                        'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
                    )
                ));
            }

            Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item', array(
                'order_item' => $orderItem,
                'quote_item' => $item
            ));
            return $item;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```